# how to delete long array elements which less than a specific long value, java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have long array like this:

```
long [] value = {111,112,113,115,116,117}
```

and a long value:

```
long limit = 114;
```

How do I remove values that are less than that long value?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to resize the array after removal ? If not , a simple for loop with if else will suffice .

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] value = { 111, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117 };
        long[] newValue = null;
        for (long l : value) {
            if (l < 114) {
                newValue = ArrayUtils.removeElement(value, l); // remove the element and return the modified array
                value = newValue;
            }
        }

    }
```

**output newValue**

```
[115, 116, 117]
```

**For Android SDK**, since it does not have `ArrayUtils`, we can go with `ArrayList`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] value = { 111, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117 };
        List myList = new ArrayList();

        for (long l : value) {
            if (!(l < 114)) {
                myList.add(l);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
[115, 116, 117]
```

Comment: The Android SDK doesn't have the `ArrayUtils` class.

Comment: @MikeM ok,i did not knew abt it, then he can use ArrayList..??

Comment: Yep. Android does have `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you only want to keep the elements that are bigger than the limit, and the array is not sorted, one efficient way is:

```
int count = 0;
for (long l : value) {
    if (l >= limit) { value[count++] = l; }
}
```

The first "count" elements of the array are bigger than "limit", and the remaining are trash. You can copy the first "count" elements to a new array:

```
long[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, 0, count);
```

Otherwise you can set the remaining items in the array ( with index bigger or equal to "count" ) to a some specific value (like 0 or -1) if it does not interfere.

If the array is sorted you can use binary search to find the index of the first element that is bigger than the limit and then create the new array.

```
int low = 0, high = value.length -1, mid = 0;
boolean match = false;
while (low <= high) {
    mid = (low+high) /2;
    long val = value[mid];
    if (val > limit) { high = mid - 1; }
    else if (val < limit) { low = mid +1; }
    else { match = true; break; }
}

long[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, (match)? mid : low, value.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are not the best way to make operation with data. In your case you can use an arrayList, sortedList, etc.